# Tensorflow: Where is tf.nn.conv2d Actually Executed?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am curious about the Tensorflow implementation of `tf.nn.conv2d(...)`. To call it, one simply runs `tf.nn.conv2d(...)`. However, I'm going down the rabbit hole trying to see where it is executed. The code is as follows (where the arrow indicates the function it ultimately calls):

```
tf.nn.conv2d(...) -> tf.nn_ops.conv2d(...) -> tf.gen_nn_ops.conv2d(...) -> _op_def_lib.apply_op("Conv2D", ...) -> ?
```

I am familiar with Tensorflow's implementation of LSTMs and the ability to easily manipulate them as one deems fit. Is the function that performs the `conv2d()` calculation written in Python, and if so, where is it? Can I see where and how the strides are executed?

Comment: one trick I use is to search for "REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER" and then look through matches for something matching conv2d

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**TL;DR:** The implementation of [`tf.nn.conv2d()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/nn.html#conv2d) is written in C++, which invokes optimized code using either Eigen (on CPU) or the cuDNN library (on GPU). You can find the implementation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8eaf671025e8cd5358278f91f7e89e2fbbe6a26b/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L115).

The chain of functions that you mentioned in the question (from `tf.nn.conv2d()` down) are Python functions for **building** a TensorFlow graph, but these do not invoke the implementation. Recall that, in TensorFlow, you first [build a symbolic graph, then execute it](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/resources/faq.html#why_does_c_tfmatmula_b_not_execute_the_matrix_multiplication_immediately).

The implementation of `tf.nn.conv2d()` is only executed happens when you call [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) passing a `Tensor` whose value depends on the result of some convolution. For example:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, 32], stddev=0.1)
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

result = sess.run(conv, feed_dict={input: ...})  # <== Execution happens here.
```

Invoking `sess.run(...)` tells TensorFlow to run all the ops that are neeeded to compute the value of `conv`, including the convolution itself. The path from here to the implementation is somewhat complicated, but goes through the following steps:

1. `sess.run()` calls the TensorFlow backend to fetch the value of `conv`.
2. The backend prunes the computation graph to work out what nodes must be executed, and places the nodes on the appropriate devices (CPU or GPU).
3. Each device is instructed to execute its subgraph, using an [executor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.h).
4. The executor eventually invokes the `tensorflow::OpKernel` that corresponds to the convolution operator, by calling its `Compute()` method.

The `"Conv2D"` OpKernel is implemented [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8eaf671025e8cd5358278f91f7e89e2fbbe6a26b/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L94), and its `Compute()` method is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8eaf671025e8cd5358278f91f7e89e2fbbe6a26b/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc#L115). Because this op is performance critical for many workloads, the implementation is quite complicated, but the basic idea is that the computation is offloaded to either the Eigen Tensor library (if running on CPU), or cuDNN's optimized GPU implementation.

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow programs as consisting of two discrete sections:

- Building the computational graph.

tf.nn.conv2d(...) -> tf.nn_ops.conv2d(...) -> tf.gen_nn_ops.conv2d(...) -> _op_def_lib.apply_op("Conv2D", ...) -> graph.create_op -> register op into graph

- Running the computational graph.

sess = tf.Session(target) -> sess.run(conv2d) -> master prune full graph to client graph -> master split client graph by task to graph partition -> register graph partition to worker -> worker split subgraph by device to graph partition -> then master notify all workers to run graph partitions -> worker notify all devices to run graph partitions -> executor will run ops by topological sort on device.

For one of op, the executor will invoke kernel implement to compute for the op.

The kernel implement of tf.nn.conv2d() is written in C++, which invokes optimized code using either Eigen (on CPU) or the cuDNN library (on GPU).