# Weights in Convolution Layers in Keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I want to know if the filters' weights in a, for example, 2D convolution layer in Keras are shared along the spatial dimensions by default. If yes, is there any way to have not shared weights?

Comment: Shared between what? what do you mean exactly? It's a convolution... Different filters have different weights and they keep the same weight for each matrix multiplication...

Answer (score 3):

I found that `LocallyConnected2D` does what I am looking for.

The `LocallyConnected2D` layer works similarly to the `Conv2D` layer, except that weights are **unshared**, that is, a different set of filters is applied at each different patch of the input.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what your asking but:

The weights in the a single convolutional layer are shared. That is, the filters share the same weights with each stride.

However The weights *between* two convolutonal layers are not shared by default in keras.

There is no getting around shared wiegths in the filters within the conv layer. Since the execution of the convolution if offloaded to C++ libraries.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34843397/4356204) for further reference, in particular:

> The implementation of tf.nn.conv2d() is written in C++, which invokes
>   optimized code using either Eigen (on CPU) or the cuDNN library (on
>   GPU). You can find the implementation here.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to have different weights for each filter or set of filters in a single conv. layer in Keras? Suppose we want to learn different features in different locations of an image.